# Add to cart PHP Rest Api (Android, ios, web)

Tags: php, rest, api, e-commerce, cart

I am writing rest api using one of the PHP cms for a eCommerce app.

The current cms has sessioncart which uses customer's session to fetch the customer detail and store the cart data.

I want to provide the api for add to cart functionality for android and ios app.

Apps and website will be linked so if user logs in through app or website he/she should be able to see the cart item.

What i cannot get is how to maintain or create the customer session for rest api

Am i doing it right?.

Any help or guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think this is too broad. You can do it with tokens, most common way for an API.

Comment: i dont want to break the existing functionality of the cms. Can you share any example

Comment: no need to break the functionality. You will just wrap the CMS API with your own API.